# create mathexpression for metric CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I have some metrics m1,m2,m3.I need to create a MathExpression metric by summing all the metrics(m1+m2+m3).
Currently,I am doing

```
 metric: new MathExpression({
  expression: "m1+m2+m3",
  usingMetrics: {
    m1: <MetricPropsMethodReturningMetric>,
    m2: <MetricPropsMethodReturningMetric>,
    m3: <MetricPropsMethodReturningMetric>
  },
}
```

But,Here I have hardcoded the metrics (m1,m2,m3) .In case I get another metric m4,m5 then I will have to change the expression.I wanted to ask How can I dynamically take the metric and have a math expression for Sum of all those metric irrespective of the number of metrics given?

Answer (score 1):

Is it just the expression string that you don't want to update? If so, then you can do `SUM(METRICS())`.

Comment: what is METRICS() here ?

Comment: It selects all the metrics you have in the list so you don't have to list them one by one.

Comment: Link to the docs that goes into METRICS() and other things: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html. And if the link becomes broken it's Amazon CloudWatch, article on "using metric math".